# как написать программу на питоне

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

помогите написать программу на питоне, используя функции    Алгоритм вычисления функции F(n) задан следующими соотношениями:
        F(n) = n при n > 15
        F(n) = 2·F(n+1) + 5n + 2, если n  15
Чему равно значение функции F(2)?

Comment: У вас прямо в условии решение написано

Answer (score 0):

```
def f(n):
    if n>15: return n
    else: return 2*f(n+1)+5*n+2

print(f(2))
```

***stdout***:

> `1441790`